# Hide select option value so user can not view it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am creating a list of drop downs. I retrieve data from my database of 3 general locations. Countries, Regions/States/Providences and Cities. So I have 3 drop downs (one for each of these general locations). And when a Country is selected I want only the regions within that Country to be an option. I put all regions in the select tag because I do not know what country the user is going to select and I am trying to avoid an AJAX call to use PHP.

**My Current HTML:**

```
<select id='countrySelect'>
  <option value='0'>Select Country</option>
  <option value='1'>United States</option>
  <option value='2'>Canada</option>
</select>
<select id='regionSelect' disabled>
  <option value='0'>Select Region/State</option>
  <option value='1' data-id='1'>California</option>
  <option value='2' data-id='2'>British Columbia</option>
</select>
<select id='citySelect' disabled>
  <option value='0'>Select City/Area</option>
  <option value='1' data-id='1'>San Fransisco</option>
  <option value='2' data-id='1'>Los Angeles</option>
  <option value='3' data-id='2'>Victoria</option>
  <option value='4' data-id='2'>Vancouver</option>
</select>
```

The value corresponds to the idea of that location in the database (Countries, Regions, and Cities are each their own database). Data-id refers to the id of where that option is located. For example: California's data-id is 1 meaning it is in country 1. And the United States has a value of 1 so therefore California is in the United States. It works the same for cities in regions. But when a user clicks Unites States. I want British Columbia to not BE SEEN (not disabled, because when they are disabled they are still visible just not selectable. And I don't want them removed because they are gone forever). I want a cross browser way to hide them and if they choose Canada then everything else will be 'hidden' from the user. I only made it for the Country and Region so far. The city doesn't work yet because I wanted to figure this out first.

**My current jQuery:**

```
 $('#countrySelect').on('change', function() {
  // set the country ID equal to the selected value
  var countryId = this.value;
  // enable all regions to be selected
  $("#regionSelect > option").prop('disabled', false);
  // loop through to disable regions that cannot be selected
  $("#regionSelect > option").each(function() {
        if($(this).data('id')!= countryId && $(this).val() != 0) {
            $(this).hide():
        }
    });
  // if a country was selected allow the user to select a region
  if(countryId > 0){
    $('#regionSelect').prop('disabled',false);
  }
  else {
    $('#regionSelect').prop('disabled',true);               
    $("#regionSelect").val('0');
  }           
});
```

Comment: "I want British Columbia to not BE SEEN (not disabled, they are still visible and not removed because they are gone forever)." - Doesn't this contradict itself, not be seen but still visible?

Comment: even if you avoid using ajax,the best way is ajax ,returns json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can show all regions associated to a country based on data-id

```
$('#countrySelect').change(function()
{
    $('#regionSelect').prop('disabled',$(this).val() == "0");
    $('#regionSelect option[data-id='+$(this).val()+']').show();
    $('#regionSelect option[data-id!='+$(this).val()+']').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TmEbd/

Answer (score 1):

The main sticking point is going to be `data('id')` - you are trying to get `.prop('data-id')`.

I would do something like this

```
$("#regionSelect > option[data-id!=" + countryId + "]").hide();
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rxHLq/

New FIDDLE with redundant code removed: http://jsfiddle.net/rxHLq/1/

Updated again: http://jsfiddle.net/rxHLq/4/ (the answer from Eagle adds to my example by showing the hidden elements in case the select option is changed)

Comment: Not crossbrowser. IE does not support .hide() on option tags.